# Fitting the cumulative distribution function using MATLAB

Tags: statistics, matlab

How is it possible to make the following data more fitted when i will plot using [Cumulative_distribution_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)?

here is my code, plotted using the cdfplot

```
clear all; 
close all;
y = [23 23 23 -7.59 23 22.82 22.40 13.54 -3.97 -4.00 8.72 23 23 10.56 12.19 23 9.47 5.01 23 23 23 23 22.85 23 13.61 -0.77 -14.15 23 12.91 23 20.88 -9.42 23 -1.37 1.83 14.35 -8.30 23 15.17 23 5.01 22.28 23 21.91 21.68 -4.76 -13.50 14.35 23]
cdfplot(y)
```

Comment: How do you define 'more fitted'? [`cdfplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html) produces the empirical cumulative distribution function, no fitting.

Comment: Yeap there is no fitting in cdfplot, that's why my graph is like a staircase. I would like it to be more smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definite answer to your question, it is too broad and mainly belongs to statistics. Before doing any computation you should answer some questions:

- is there a specific distribution type which the data follow?
- is there any theoretical justification to select a distribution type and discard others?
- do I need parametric or non-parametric distribution?
- if no specific distribution type can be selected than what set of distributions should I investigate?
- how to compare the distributions, [goodness-of-fit measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)?
- what fitting method should I use, e.g. [max-likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood), [method of moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)), [Bayesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference), etc.?
- how to treat uncertainties?
- how and for what want I use the results?
- etc.

Without answering these question it is meaningless to talk about fitting distribution to data.
I give you an example how to do the fit in Matlab using maximum-likelihood method, just for illustration, but I would strongly discourage you to use it without considering the above points.

Since I have no additional background information in respect of the nature of the data, normal and [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) distributions are fitted to illustrate 1 parametric and 1 non-parametric distribution.

```
cdfplot(y)
hold on
xx = -20:40;
%normal distribution
pd_norm = fitdist(y', 'normal');

F_norm = normcdf(xx, pd_norm.mu, pd_norm.sigma);
plot(xx, F_norm, 'r')

%kernel distribution
pd_kernel1 = fitdist(y', 'kernel', 'Kernel', 'normal', 'Width', 6);

F_kernel1 = cdf(pd_kernel1, xx);
plot(xx, F_kernel1, 'g')

%kernel distribution
pd_kernel2 = fitdist(y', 'kernel', 'Kernel', 'normal', 'Width', 2);

F_kernel2 = cdf(pd_kernel2, xx);
plot(xx, F_kernel2, 'black')

legend('ecdf', 'normal', 'kernel1', 'kernel2', 'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

[image]

Comment: Completely correct, only a small addition: from a non-statistical point of view one could simply use a smoothing interpolation method, e.g. a cubic smoothing spline (`csaps` from the curve fitting toolbox). This is conceptually similar to the kernel estimate, but might be better able to adapt smoothness locally, compared to a fixed kernel bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you a lot for broadly answering to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
h = cdfplot(y)
cftool( get(h,'XData'), get(h,'YData') )
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, but as it mentioned before by [Arpi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4063376/arpi) not every data fits to the curve fitting toolbox.