# Matlab curve fitting toolbox - what custom fitting function?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

This is the data, and a badly fitting exp2 fit:

http://oi64.tinypic.com/10e0di0.jpg

It seems easy to fit at first glance, but I have found it difficult to find a custom equation that fits this data. Exp2 and gauss2 are the usual candidates but I couldn't find a combination that work. It is important for me to preserve the monotony of the data, so polynomials make a bad fit, it is also important not to significantly overshoot or undershoot the data at the edges (like the shown exp2 fit). Preserving the sharply increasing middle part is less important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example data set:

```
x =  0    0.0200    0.0400    0.0600    0.0800    0.1000    0.1200    0.1400     0.1600    0.1800    0.2000    0.2200    0.2400    0.2600    0.2800    0.3000 0.3200    0.3400    0.3600    0.3800    0.4000    0.4200    0.4400    0.4600    0.4800    0.5000    0.5200    0.5400    0.5600    0.5800    0.6000    0.6200 0.6400    0.6600    0.6800    0.7000    0.7200    0.7400    0.7600    0.7800    0.8000    0.8200    0.8400    0.8600    0.8800    0.9000    0.9200    0.9400 0.9600    0.9800    1.0000

y = 0.0096    0.0093    0.0092    0.0092    0.0094    0.0097    0.0102    0.0107    0.0114    0.0123    0.0132    0.0144    0.0157    0.0171    0.0189    0.0209  0.0232    0.0259    0.0291    0.0328    0.0373    0.0426    0.0491    0.0570    0.0667    0.0789    0.0941    0.1135    0.1383    0.1699    0.2101    0.2605 0.3214    0.3918    0.4682    0.5455    0.6184    0.6834    0.7389    0.7848    0.8221    0.8521    0.8761    0.8954    0.9108    0.9232    0.9332    0.9413  0.9479    0.9533    0.9576
```

Comment: That looks like a cumulative distribution function (CDF). The `cftool` is not optimized for fitting distributions (as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880817/fitting-the-cumulative-distribution-function-using-matlab)). Either use the `Interpolant` method and the piecewise polynomials, or if you really want to find a good mathematical fit, you'll have to code the math necessary for it, and it would be better asked in another Stack Exchange site ([example](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best)).

Comment: You are right, it does behave like a cdf. I have a lot of data like that (tens of thousands) from numerical integrations with curves that vary a lot but all resemble a normal cdf, therefore I managed to get very good fits using the regular Matlab non-linear least-squares fitting to the function 'm*((erf(a*x - b) + 1) + c*x) + d'. As usual it took a LOT of playing with the starting points to manage to get ALL the different data to fit correctly. So thank you, problem solved.

Comment: Hey ssteinberg, I came across this function on the Matlab file exchange: [sigm_fit](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42641-sigm-fit). Not sure it will help you but it 's worth having a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of it. However it didn't give good results. My data isn't exactly a CDF.